# Word to represent 5 bits of data?

Tags: binary, binary-data

A "byte" is 8 bits.
A "nibble" (sometimes "nybble") represents 4 bits.

Is there a term to represent a group of 5 bits?

Currently working on a Base32 encoder and need a term to represent a single base32 character, which is represented by 5 bits.

Comment: Bytes have not always and are not always 8 bits, these are not hard and fast rules.  but other than the term byte there is unlikely to be a term for 5 bits.

Comment: It may appear that you got the "nibble" description [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information#Nibble). Just a bit below, in the [Obsolete and unusual units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information#Obsolete_and_unusual_units) section, there is "5 bits: pentad, pentade, nickel, nyckle".

Comment: GSerg- I knew the word nibble from common usage in computer science. If you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer to my question. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not convinced that an "obsolete and unusual" unit is a proper answer. I'm happy to leave it as a comment. If the term works for you, feel free to make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [sources on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information), a group of 5 bits has historically been referred to by a variety of names such as a:

- pentad
- pentade
- nickel
- nyckle